# Page Layout field

Tags: column, page-layout

I need some help to update a field in page layout. I don't have much information but I am trying my best to explain the issue.

In our page-layout we have a hidden field for the owner to choose to help for search content query. And now my manager asked me to update this field and I am not to sure where is the data for this field are coming from.

So my question is how can I update this field and add more options?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to list settings for the pages library. Click on the field and you can see if it's a:

- Choice field (most likely): add options directly on field
- Managed metadata field: Go to term store and add term
- Lookup field: Go to corresponding list and add item

Comment: Thanks Joakim, where would be the list settings for the pages library?

Comment: Go to "Site contents" and, if you have adequate permissions, you will be able to select library settings there.